# Why this MessageBox does not appear?

Tags: c#, event-handling, bluetooth, message

I Have Code for EventHandler like this below.

```
void ConnectionManager_Error(object sender, EventArgs<string> e)
{
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
         State = ConnectState.NotFound;
         MessageBox.Show(e.Value);
    });
}
```

My Problem:

MessageBox never appears even when the device is not connected to the computer.

I think that comes MessageBox supposed that show error messages. 
Can someone show me what is wrong?

**Note:**

I have this code that I thought would trigger ConnectionManager Error EventHandler.

```
private void LogError(string error)
{
    if (Error != null)
        Error(this, new EventArgs<string>(error));
}
```

I also have this code that gives an error message containing the string  to LogError method.

```
int lasterror = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (lasterror != 0)
        LogError("Bluetooth API returned: " + lasterror.ToString());
```

or

```
 if (BluetoothSetServiceState(IntPtr.Zero, ref device, ref HumanInterfaceDeviceServiceClass_UUID, BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_ENABLE) != 0)
     LogError("Failed to connect to wiimote controller");
```

**Another Hint**

To be more specific, I also already have the code below:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs<string>> Error;
```

and

```
ConnectionManager.Error += new EventHandler<EventArgs<string>>(ConnectionManager_Error);
```

And also this class:

```
public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T Value
    {
         get;
         set;
    }

     public EventArgs(T value)
            : base()
     {
        Value = value;
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Set a breakpoint in the first line of the event handler

Comment: I've tried it, it looks like nothing is wrong. 
is it possible it happened because I execute this project in different  VStudio versions from the VS used to create this code? 
_silly question._

Comment: Is it standard BeginInvoke that executes code in the separate thread?

Comment: Is this happening in a non-UI thread? Or what else is the reason for BeginInvoke?

Answer (score 0):

Is it standard BeginInvoke that executes code in the separate thread?

You have to work with GUI methods only in GUI thread. 
To switch to the GUI thread please try Control.IsInvokeRequired and Control.Invoke methods.